# Split text files into two groups - unsupervised learning

Tags: text-classification, unsupervised-learning

Imagine, you are a librarian and during time you
have classified a bunch of text files (approx 100)
with a general ambiguous keyword.

Every text file is actually a topic of keyword_meaning1
or a topic of keyword_meaning2.

Which unsupervised learning approach would you use,
to split the text files into two groups?

What precision (in percentage) of correct classification
can be achieved according to a number of text files?

Or can be somehow indicated in one group, that there is
a need of a librarian to check certain files, because
they may be classifed incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest starting point would be to use a naive Bayes classifier. It's hard to speculate about the expected precision. You have to test it yourself. Just get a program for e-mail spam detection and try it out. For example, SpamBayes (http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) is a quite good starting point and easily hackable. SpamBayes has a nice feature that it will label messages as "unsure" when there is no clear separation between two classes.

Edit: When you really want unsupervised clustering method, then perhaps something like Carrot2 (http://project.carrot2.org/) is more appropriate.

Comment: Isn't Bayes method supervised? With a training phase? Or this is some modification?

Comment: Yes, it's supervised. I noticed from the problem statement that you have class labels available, so the naive Bayes seemed the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Thanks for carrot2.